# Google Apps Marketplace SDK : Gadget for calendar

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-apps-marketplace

We're willing to write a Google gadget installed through Google MarketPlace that would integrate into the Google calendar GUI.
We want to add a button in the event form displayed when creating a calendar appointment.

We have no clue where to start and if it's feasible.
The Google marketplace sdk doc talks about COB (gadget for gmail) but nothing about calendar GUI interaction.

Any idea where to start?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be much of an answer, but I don't have enough points to comment yet.  I'm trying to do the same thing.  I've seen this implemented via a chrome extension.  Check out the gotomeeting extension, it does exactly the sort of thing you and I are looking to do.

I believe it only works for chrome and is basically a javascript that works its magic.  [Here is a link to some source code I was able to find on the subject](https://bitbucket.org/callawaycloud/gotomeetinghack/src/c3f7b1df5b1d92d03554370798c7c59825c9fd62?at=master).  You're a better man than I if you can figure it out.